# pwdx returning gibberish

Tags: process, linux

pwdx is supposed to print out the current working directory of a process given a process id.

Normally this looks something like:

```
$ sudo pwdx 1
1: /

$ pwdx $$
5251: /home/foo
```

One one machine I have it always returns the same gibberish string

```
$ pwdx 1
1: H?l$?L?|$?H?-

$ pwdx 24535
24535: H?l$?L?|$?H?-

$ pwdx $$
24351: H?l$?L?|$?H?-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the equivalent:

```
readlink -f /proc/PID/cwd
```

Answer (score 0):

Intresting. pwdx is really simple, code-wise; it just resolve the 'cwd' symlink target in /prod/pid

What do you get from this?

> ls -l /proc/$$/cwd

Also, what distribution/architecture are you on? Default character set? Here's a link to the source if you want to try building your own.  You shouldn't need to do anything outside of "make".

http://procps.sourceforge.net/

Comment: distribution = it's Ubuntu server 10.04.2 x86_64; I suspect the character set is utf8 but I don't know how to check; /proc/[pid]/cwd seems to work correctly

Comment: actually it's 9.04